# Jquery on selector for element parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-on

To use jquery `on` method instead of deprecated `live` method in this simple case

```
$("#myForm").live('submit', function() {
   alert("submit");
});
```

would be

```
$(document).on('submit', '#myForm', function() {
  alert("submit");
});
```

Now, how to do the same with "pure" `on`, without extra things(like e.g. assign id to form and then use that id as a selector or smth like that) in this case

```
$("#myInput").parents("form").live('submit', function() {
   alert("submit");
});
```

thanks

Comment: but will it work if my form was created after document ready ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the event handler on all form submissions, then test to see if the form contains the input you care about inside it.

```
jQuery(document).on('submit', 'form', function (evt) {
    if (jQuery(evt.target).find('#myInput').length === 0) {
        return;
    }
    // Otherwise run the rest of the function normally
});
```

Comment: will this work: ``$(document).on('submit',$("#myInput").parents("form"), function() {
   alert("submit");
});``??

Comment: you could even take out === 0 , just the .length would do the trick here to return true or false

Comment: @EhsanSajjad — No, the second argument needs to be a selector.